# Rails test can't find route when it clearly exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, so I am tired, and new to rails so possibly am missing something super basic.  Anyways, I just started a new project and am implementing a simply controller for static pages.  Wrote some unit tests just to make sure all my routes are correct (there are only 4 so far).  Three of them pass but the fourth gives me this error message:

```
  1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_terms_of_service_should_return_success:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"terms", :controller=>"static_pages
"}
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTes
t>'
```

Its saying it can't find the route.  However, when I rake routes it clearly exists:

```
  about GET  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact GET  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
privacy GET  /privacy(.:format) static_pages#privacy
  terms GET  /terms(.:format)   static_pages#terms_of_service
```

Here is that part of routes.rb:

```
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'privacy' => 'static_pages#privacy'
  get 'terms' => 'static_pages#terms_of_service'
```

and here is the code for the test that is failing:

```
 test "terms_of_service should return success" do
    get 'terms'
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'title', "Terms Of Service"
 end
```

I can visit localhost:3000/terms directly in the browser and it works.  Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller tests don't test routes, the test actions. You want:

```
get 'terms_of_service'
```

Comment: Ah thanks :) I knew it was something simple.  So many nuances when learning a new framework.  If I were to use the get method in an integration test, would it test a route in that case?